# Java - Using Scanner multiple times

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am currently trying to take in input from a user in the console, do some actions, and then take in more input from the console.

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    System.out.print("Enter input: ");
    String foo = userInput.nextLine();
    //do stuff with foo
}
```

whenever I do this, the first run through of the loop works perfectly, but every subsequent run prints foo out as nothing, and it does not let me add more input.

```
//above code
System.out.println(foo);
//nothing prints
```

How should I make it so that it will prompt for input every time, and make sure that it doesn't just use a blank string?

Comment: java.util.Scanner does not have a `readLine` method. So you are using a different Scanner class...

Comment: I don't think you're giving us full information. It's very likely your "do stuff with foo" code is causing something strange to happen, because using your code as is works for me (and, I imagine, the others who have tried to help you.)

Comment: Please, make sure that you have SOME sort of escape (`break`) to get out of a `while(true)`. It's horrible practice because it can lead to huge problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter input: ");
        String foo = userInput.nextLine();

        if (foo.length () == 0) {
            break;
        }

        //do stuff with foo
        System.out.format("[%s]\n",foo);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... downvoter, please comment? It appears to answer the question given (although the question is quite unclear).

Comment: Also, this answer does not successfully answer my question. All this does is cancel out of the loop when foo.length() == 0, which is every time the method is run...

Comment: foo.length() == 0 will only happen if you push enter first.  Maybe you are not explaining yourself well.

Answer (score -1):

there is no readLine method in Scanner class
you may use it like that

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter input: ");
            String foo = userInput.nextLine();
            System.out.println(foo);
}
```

Comment: sorry about that mistake in the code. But no, this still leaves a blank output after each run of the loop

Comment: try using String foo = userInput.next()+userInput.nextLine();